# 'vbc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to write a simple VB program using Visual Source Code. Started with the simple

msgbox "Hello world"

When I run it I get the message: 'vbc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I've tried every "solution" I can find on the 'net but nothing works.

Comment: `msgbox "Hello world"` is VBA, with which you tagged your question. 'vbc' is the Visual Basic .NET compiler, which is not VBA. So which language are you trying to use?

Comment: Didn't know that. I'm trying to use VBA because I already have everything written for VBA in Access. I installed an extension for VBA but I assumed it would provide the appropriate command line. I don't see a way to customize this. I'm new to Visual Source Code. Thanks, @GSerg

Comment: VBA, by definition, is Visual Basic for Applications, and does not run outside of an application. If you want to write code in VSCode for some reasons, you need to copy it back to an Office app to run.